# How to set javascript var's innerHTML to php/html text

Tags: php, javascript, html, escaping, innerhtml

I thought I understood how to escape things, but this is just blowing my mind. I need to take this html/php combo text:

```
<select name="mainUsers" class="manageSelect">
<?php
     $users = getAllUsersByUserId($userid);
     echo'<option value="choose">Select a user...</option>';    
     while($user = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
         echo'<option value='.$user['fname'].' '.$user['lname'].'>'.$user['fname'].' '.$user['lname'].'</option>';      
     }
?>
</select>;
```

and set it as the innerHTML of a javascript var. Its crashing because I don't have my escape syntax correct.

EDIT: Sorry for being unclear. This isn't working and I don't know why:

```
cell2.innerHTML = 
<?php
     echo '<select name="mainUsers" class="manageSelect">';
     $families = getAllFamiliesByUserId($userid);
     echo '<div id="famSelect"><option value="choose">Select a family...</option></div>';       
     while($family = mysql_fetch_array($families)) {
         echo '<div id="famSelect"><option value="'.$family['name'].'">'.$family['name'].'</option></div>';     
     }
     echo '</select>';
?>;
```

Comment: Your value attribute in the option tags isn't quoted

Comment: What do you mean when you say `Its crashing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set innerHTML to a string containing HTML.  In JavaScript, you need to delimit that string with quotes, so:

```
cell2.innerHTML = 
<?php
    echo '\'<select name="mainUsers" class="manageSelect">';
    $families = getAllFamiliesByUserId($userid);
    echo '<div id="famSelect"><option value="choose">Select a family...</option></div>';       
    while($family = mysql_fetch_array($families)) {
        echo '<div id="famSelect"><option value="'.$family['name'].'">'.$family['name'].'</option></div>';     
    }
    echo '</select>\';';
?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a space between **echo** and the string being generated.

Also, the HTML you are generating isn't putting quotes around the option's value attribute.

Try this out:
`echo '<option value="'.$user['fname'].' '.$user['lname'].'">'.$user['fname'].' '.$user['lname'].'</option>';`

Answer (score 1):

Theres problem with your quoting, it certanly throws a javascript error. Right now you have code like:

```
cell2.innerHTML = <select>...</select>
```

But it should be

```
cell2.innerHTML = '<select>...</select>'
```

So put single quotes around you php tags

```
cell2.innerHTML = '<?php
//...
?>';
```

And this work without any escaping cause you dont use any single quotes inside your html code. But escaping is simple: Just replace all single quotes with \'. Like so:
cell2.innerHTML = '

```
<?php
     $html = '<select name="mainUsers" class="manageSelect">';
     $families = getAllFamiliesByUserId($userid);
     $html .= '<div id="famSelect"><option value="choose">Select a family...</option></div>';       
     while($family = mysql_fetch_array($families)) {
         $html .= '<div id="famSelect"><option value="'.$family['name'].'">'.$family['name'].'</option></div>';     
     }
     $html .= '</select>';
     echo addslashes($html);
     // Addslashes also slahses double quotes("). If this is causing problems try: echo str_replace("'", "\\'", $html);
?>';
```